# Deploying basic node.js app to openshift gives errors on git push

Tags: node.js, openshift

- I set up a default node application using the procedure on the openshift website,
- did a git clone on my ubuntu box,
- edited the readme.md,
- did a commit
- and tried pushing to the repo
- got a lot of npm fetch failed errors, and a lot of - Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN errors

  ...
      remote: npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.5.tgz
      remote: npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

  ```
  remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/-/negotiator-0.3.0.tgz
  remote: npm ERR! Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
  remote: npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1283:32)
  remote: npm ERR!     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
  remote: npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:896:10)
  remote: npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:430:15)
  remote: npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:304:10)
  remote: npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:344:25)
  remote: npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:211:10)
  remote: npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:201:5)
  remote: npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:172:11)
  remote: npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:557:24)
  remote: npm ERR!     at flow (_stream_readable.js:566:7)
  remote: npm ERR!     at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:598:5)

  remote: npm info preuninstall commander@1.3.2
  remote: npm info uninstall commander@1.3.2
  remote: npm info postuninstall commander@1.3.2
  remote: npm ERR!
  remote: npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
  remote: npm ERR!     /var/lib/openshift/53100d354382ec58b5000032/app-root/runtime/repo/npm-debug.log
  remote: npm ERR! not ok code 0
  remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
  remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/53100d354382ec58b5000032/nodejs
  remote:
  remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option
  To ssh://53100d354382ec58b5000032@pmcloud-stellagreen.rhcloud.com/~/git/pmcloud.git/
     c851403..54dc73a  master -> master
  ```

Looking at the logs is not helping.
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npm acknowledged this error on their blog: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more

> The solution: either
>
> 1) upgrade your version of npm
>
> `npm install npm -g`
>   - or -
>
> 2) tell your current version of npm to use known registrars
>
> `npm config set ca ""`

Comment: npm config set ca "" worked for me.  I tried to install a new version of npm but I got the same Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Answer (score 1):

ssh to your app then set http for npm

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

push your code again

Comment: Not using https is more of a dirty hack

Answer (score 0):

**Send here your package.js**.

Look at dependencies block:

```
negotiator:"0.4.1"
```