# npm error while deploying node.js app to openshift

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sails.js, openshift

I just generated the node.js skeleton app with sails + react following [this example](https://github.com/mixxen/sails-react-example).
Then I followed [these instructions](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/deployment/hosting) on how to deploy a sails app to Openshift.

On git push I always receive the following error:

```
remote: npm info postuninstall babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx@6.5.2
remote: npm info preuninstall babel-preset-react@6.5.0
remote: npm info uninstall babel-preset-react@6.5.0
remote: npm info postuninstall babel-preset-react@6.5.0
remote: npm ERR! not ok code 0
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 47)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/***/nodejs
remote:
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
To ssh://***@***.rhcloud.com/~/git/***.git/
   ***  master -> master
```

Searching for a solution I found this: [Deploying basic node.js app to openshift gives errors on git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086782/deploying-basic-node-js-app-to-openshift-gives-errors-on-git-push)

but neither `npm install npm -g` or `npm config set ca ""` solved the problem.

this is part of my package.json:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.6.0",
    "npm": ">= 1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "bower": "^1.7.7",
    "ejs": "2.3.4",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
```

Any help?